# Ruby user messaging error when creating new converstation

Tags: ruby

My Ruby app suddenly has errors when creating a new conversation between users.  It has been working fine I believe until I integrated imagemagick, and AWS S3 gems to my app.  Also the issue is only in development, my heroku version is not affected by this.  here is the error:

> Net::SMTPFatalError in ConversationsController#create
>
> 550 Unauthenticated senders not allowed

the conversation = current_user.... line is highlighted line in my conversations controller:

```
def create
  recipients = User.find_by(id: params[:recipient_id])
  conversation = current_user.send_message(recipients, conversation_params[:body], conversation_params[:subject]).conversation
  flash[:success] = "Your message was successfully sent!"
  redirect_to conversation_path(conversation)
end
```

Again, its working fine when pushed to Heroku, this error only appears in the development environment.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What's going on in that `send_message` method?

Comment: I would guess it's that your production environment has some things setup that your dev environment doesn't have access to.

Comment: I believe that the error is related to some lack of communication between mailboxer and devise.  It happens If the two users are in a conversation (user A, and B), and for example, user "A" deletes his account, then user "B" can no longer access her inbox.  Basically I need to figure out how to get mailboxer to delete all messages in user  "A" inbox when he deletes his profile, so that it doesn't affect user "B" inbox functionality, or any other users who have been in contact.  I will be creating a separate question  for this error with the right details.